# Need help in string conversion based on multiple rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a func_name column. I have set of rules to be forced on this func_name column to create a func_short_name.

The desired logic for func_short_name is:

1. use whatever is to the right of '>'; preceded by whatever comes after each 
   '+' or '@' from FUNC_NAME field
2. Each time '+' or '@' appears, append it to the func_short_name

Example:

func_name: toolbox/matlab/cefclient/+matlab/+internal/getOpenPort.p>getOpenPort

func_short_name : matlab.internal.getOpenPort

The above example appends 'matlab' with 'internal' since they are followed by a '+' and the 'getOpenPort' since it is to the right of '>'

How do I take in account for each occurence of '+' or 'a'. Could someone help me construct a SQL or stored proc? Thanks!

I have tried implementing the rules separately but I am unable to do a recursive append of each occurence of '+' or '@'

```
select  substring(FUNC_NAME,charindex('a',FUNC_NAME)+1,100)
FROM table

select  FUNC_NAME,
charindex('@',FUNC_NAME)+1,
charindex('/',FUNC_NAME)-1
from table

select  concat(substring(FUNC_NAME,charindex('@',FUNC_NAME)+1,charindex('/',FUNC_NAME)-1),'.',substring(FUNC_NAME,charindex('>',FUNC_NAME)+1,100))
FROM table
```

func_name: toolbox/matlab/cefclient/+matlab/+internal/getOpenPort.p>getOpenPort

func_short_name : matlab.internal.getOpenPort

Another example:
func name:
toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/@sym/@aem/diag.m>diag

func_short_name:
sym.aem.diag

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: The logic here doesn't make much sense. You find the first '+' in the string. Then remove the '+' and change all '/' to '.'. So far so good I guess. But then you also remove '.p'? Is that correct?

Comment: if the function is +x/+y/+z/efg>abc then function short name should be x.y.z.abc

Comment: My SQL Server Version - 11

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it regardless of the version of SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @func_name VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @func_short_name VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @func_name_length INT;
DECLARE @start_position INT = 0;
DECLARE @end_position INT = 0;
DECLARE @gt_position INT = 0;

SET @func_name = 'toolbox/matlab/cefclient/+matlab/+internal/getOpenPort.p>getOpenPort';
--SET @func_name = 'toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/@sym/@aem/diag.m>diag';

SET @i = 1;
SET @func_name_length = LEN(@func_name);

-- loop through string character by character
WHILE @i <= @func_name_length
BEGIN
    IF (SUBSTRING(@func_name, @i, 1)) IN ('+', '@')
    BEGIN
        SET @start_position = @i;
    END;

    -- ending character found after starting character has been found
    IF (SUBSTRING(@func_name, @i, 1)) = '/'
       AND @start_position > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @end_position = @i;
        SET @func_short_name = @func_short_name
                               + SUBSTRING(@func_name, @start_position + 1, (@end_position - 1) - @start_position)
                               + '.';
        SET @start_position = 0;
    END;

    SET @i += 1;

END;

-- find greater than character
SET @gt_position = CHARINDEX('>', @func_name);

SET @func_short_name = @func_short_name + SUBSTRING(@func_name, @gt_position + 1, @func_name_length - @gt_position);

SELECT @func_name AS [FUNC NAME], @func_short_name AS [FUNC SHORT NAME];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only if it's SQL Server 2017+**

Initialization:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Func_Name NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @Table (Func_Name)VALUES
     ('toolbox/matlab/cefclient/+matlab/+internal/getOpenPort.p>getOpenPort')
    ,('toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/@sym/@aem/diag.m>diag')
;
```

The Code:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.[value],'+',''),'@',''),'.') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn DESC) AS [Result]
FROM (
    SELECT b.ID,j.[value],ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY j.[Key] DESC) AS [rn]
    FROM (
        SELECT '["' + REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Func_Name,'/','","'),'>','","') + '"]' AS [value]
            ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [ID]
        FROM @Table t
    ) b
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.[value]) j
) a
WHERE (a.[value] LIKE '[+]%' OR a.[value] LIKE '[@]%' OR a.rn = 1 /*last piece*/)
GROUP BY a.ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution based on a recursive common table expression works with any SQL server version as of 2005 but is not really strict when it comes to the separating characters. The pattern `'%[@+>]%'` looks for any one of the characters: `@`, `+` or `>`. It does return the desired result though: `matlab.internal.getOpenPort`

```
declare @f varchar(255); 
set @f='toolbox/matlab/cefclient/+matlab/+internal/getOpenPort.p>getOpenPort'+'/';

With rcte as (
 select 0 n,@f str, patindex('%[@+>]%',@f) p union all
 select p, substring(str, p+1,255), 
   patindex('%[@+>]%',substring(str, p+1,255)) 
 from rcte where p>0
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '.' +LEFT(str,charindex('/',str)-1)
      FROM rcte
      WHERE n>0
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') short
```

`@f` is the variable containing the long function name (with an added `/` at the end) that needs to be converted.

See here for a demo: https://rextester.com/MFVO10768